# How Can I check linux distribution of my server in terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, operating-system, centos, debian

I am trying to check which linux distribution is my server is running on. I tried some commands like `lsb_release -d` but no luck

`lsb_release -d` in terminal but saying command not found
`/etc/*-release` this is also not working, saying no such directory
`/proc/version` same output as above

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

This command will show information about the distribution without installing any additional packages. It should work on most distros.